# SwiftUI different behavior on different iOS versions

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios13

I have been developing an app with minimum iOS 13, but whole development process was done on iOS 15. Now when testing the iOS 13 devices, I noticed some problems.

Minimalistic example: You have a list of items, where each item contains leading icon, with a title and a subtitle vertically stacked. To adapt to various screen sizes, I attached a `.minimumScaleFactor()` to the texts so they would scale down when needed. That's working nicely on iOS 15. After a whole lot of testing, it also works on iOS 13.4 that is the oldest where I've got it working, so, iOS 13 - <13.4 is in question here.

On the screenshot you can see iPhone 8 13.3 vs iPhone 8 13.4, the text is scaled down even when there is space available. On iPhone 6s Plus 13.3 there is even more available space (screen size).

[image: iOS comparison]

And the code:

```
struct Viewwww: View {
    var title = "This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title "
    var subtitle = "This is a subtitle This is a subtitle This is a subtitle This is a subtitle This is a subtitle "
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Onboarding test").font(.title).multilineTextAlignment(.center).lineLimit(2)
            Spacer()
            buildItem()
            buildItem()
            buildItem()
            buildItem()
            buildItem()
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .padding(.top, 30)
    }
    @ViewBuilder
    func buildItem() -> some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 20){
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "pin").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 44, height: 44)
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10){
                Text(title).font(Font.title).minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                Text(subtitle).font(Font.body).minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                
            }
            Spacer()
            
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity).background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

So anyone has experienced this, and can help? Thank you!

Comment: I will advise you if possible to avoid iOS13 and start deploying from iOS14+. SwiftUI has evolved since then by much and iOS13 has bugs from earlier versions. also worth checking iOS13 distribution today as it is supposed to be very low (some sites may offer that information)